# matplotlib won't work on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I'm having a problem getting matplotlib to work in ubuntu 10.10.

First I install the matplotlib using apt-get, and later I found that the version is 0.99 and some examples on the official site just won't work. Then I download the 1.01 version and install it without uninstalling the 0.99 version. To make the situation more specific, here is the configuration:

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: 1.0.1
                python: 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39)  [GCC
                        4.4.5]
              platform: linux2

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                 numpy: 1.6.0b1
             freetype2: 12.2.6

OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
                libpng: 1.2.44
               Tkinter: no
                        * Using default library and include directories for
                        * Tcl and Tk because a Tk window failed to open.
                        * You may need to define DISPLAY for Tk to work so
                        * that setup can determine where your libraries are
                        * located. Tkinter present, but header files are not
                        * found. You may need to install development
                        * packages.
              wxPython: no
                        * wxPython not found
            pkg-config: looking for pygtk-2.0 gtk+-2.0
                        * Package pygtk-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config
                        * search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
                        * containing `pygtk-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH
                        * environment variable No package 'pygtk-2.0' found
                        * Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config
                        * search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
                        * containing `gtk+-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH
                        * environment variable No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
                        * You may need to install 'dev' package(s) to
                        * provide header files.
                  Gtk+: no
                        * Could not find Gtk+ headers in any of
                        * '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include', '.'
       Mac OS X native: no
                    Qt: no
                   Qt4: no
                 Cairo: 1.8.8

OPTIONAL DATE/TIMEZONE DEPENDENCIES
              datetime: present, version unknown
              dateutil: 1.4.1
                  pytz: 2010b

OPTIONAL USETEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: 8.71
                 latex: no
               pdftops: 0.14.3

[Edit setup.cfg to suppress the above messages]
```

and now i can import matplotlib but once i run the example code, it just terminated and I get no results.  I tried to 'clean install' several times, which means I delete all the files include the .matplotlib and the matplotlib directory under dist-package, but I still can't get things done.

What makes weirder is that after I reinstall the 0.99 version, it works pretty well.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to install `tk-dev` and `pygtk2.0-dev` (or similar) and `gtk-dev` packages (naming may vary) and then rebuild...

Answer (score 2):

Ben Gamari has [packaged](https://launchpad.net/~bgamari/+archive/matplotlib-unofficial) matplotlib 1.0 for Ubuntu.

Comment: adding to this, use the package provided in the synaptic package manager.  It works fine for me.

Comment: The one in Ubuntu is still 0.99. Synaptic won't find any fancier packages than apt-get.

Comment: """Not allowed here
Sorry, you don't have permission to access this page or the information in this page is not shared with you."""

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with `pip`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

I just tested this and it should install matplotlib 1.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on Ubuntu 12.04. I solved it installing **python-gtk2-dev** and re-installing **matplotlib**:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2-dev
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

The message about dependencies changed to:

```
  Gtk+: gtk+: 2.24.10, glib: 2.32.3, pygtk: 2.24.0,
        pygobject: 2.28.6
```