# plot window doesn't show - Tkinter present but header  files are not found.  

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an application in python2.7 which runs fine.

Because i wanted to run it on a different laptop,i installed the matplotlib1.1 .

The problem is that the application finishes but no plot window exists.

Problem with Gtk or Tk? I tried to do in the matplotlibrc file "backend:TkAgg" or "GtkAgg" but still the same.

I forgot to mention that the laptop runs linux.

----------EDIT-------------------

I tried the installation again and it shows a message:

> You may need to define display for tk to work so that setup can
>   determine where your libraries are located.Tkinter present but header
>   files are not found.

Some part of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sc
from matplotlib.animation import ArtistAnimation

...........

fig=plt.gcf()
ani=ArtistAnimation(fig,result,interval=10,repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's a shot in the dark without any code.

Comment: You got to show the code. For starters: do you call `figure.show`?

Comment: @John Riselvato:It doesn't has to do with the code.The code runs fine.The problem is with the installation of matplotlib in another PC.I put some code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556360/matplotlib-wont-work-on-ubuntu-10-10).
Finally!
(I have done manual install because it wanted the version 1.1)

I tried this :

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 2):

Even with TkAgg, matplotlib does not necessarily show the plot until you explicitly tell it to.

If you use pylab, you can explicitly cause it to show with something like this:

```
import pylab
pylab.plot([1,2,1,3])
pylab.show()
```

The call to show() will return when you close the window.

You can make it automatically show when you do a plot by writing

```
interactive: true
```

in your matplolibrc file.  There is a system-wide config file in mpl-data/matplotlibrc in the installed packate.  You have a personal config in ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc

Some systems seem to have interactive=true by default, others do not.

Comment: Start python and enter the commands "import Tkinter", then "Tkinter.Tk()".  If you do not get a window, you have a Tk problem, not a matplotlib problem.  I don't recognize that error message, but it seems to be hinting that you may need to install TCL and TK, using the package manager for your linux distribution.

Comment: :I did the above and it gives me a window.So,sth else is happening?